# How does the Chrome Geolocation Sensor work?

Tags: geolocation, google-chrome-devtools

There is an option within the Chrome dev tools which allows you to change your ubication (More Tools > Sensors). How does it work internally? Does it add an extra HTTP header indicating the GEO coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it changes the cookie that's sent with the request:

This is the cookie for Mountain View (California, Google HQ):

```
Cookie: UULE=a+cm9sZToxIHByb2R1Y2VyOjEyIHByb3ZlbmFuY2U6NiB0aW1lc3RhbXA6MTUyMjc1NDM1MDc1MjAwMCBsYXRsbmd7bGF0aXR1ZGVfZTc6MzczODYwNTIwIGxvbmdpdHVkZV9lNzotMTIyMDgzODUxMH0gcmFkaXVzOjkzMDAw
```

Discard the `UULE=a+` and what you're left with is a Base64 encoded string. Decoding that becomes:

```
role:1 producer:12 provenance:6 timestamp:1522754350752000 latlng{latitude_e7:373860520 longitude_e7:-1220838510} radius:93000
```

Within that is the `longitude` and `latitude`, but I'm not sure what the other parts refer to. Guessing the `radius` is the radius from the centre of that long/lat (in metres?).

Hope that helps.

Comment: For details, see https://valentin.app/uule.html